# aligning burger menu to right side of screen

Tags: html, css

I have an animated burger menu that is on the left of the screen. When you click on the burger the menu expands to the right. However I want the menu to be on the right hand side. When I use float right the menu moves to the top right however it is still expanding to the right so it moves off the screen, is there any way I could flip the menu so it is expanding to the left. If anyone doesn't know what I am talking about this is the code I am using https://codepen.io/woodwoerk/pen/BoEGYZ

```
.menu {
margin: 0 20px 0 0;
padding-left: 1.25em;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
width: 30px;
height: 50px;
text-align: right;
float: right;
}

expand {
 box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) -2.5px 5px 7.5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 2.5px 5px 7.5px;
width: 200px;
height: 50px;

-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.menu-top-expand {
 top: 50px;
 background: #FFF8E1;

-webkit-transition: all 0.5s 0.2s, left 0.1s;
      transition: all 0.5s 0.2s, left 0.1s;
}

.menu-middle-expand {
top: 100px;
background: #FFECB3;

-webkit-transition: all 0.5s 0.1s, left 0.1s;
      transition: all 0.5s 0.1s, left 0.1s;
 }
.menu-bottom2-expand {
top: 200px;
background: #FFECB3;

-webkit-transition: all 0.5s 0.1s, left 0.1s;
      transition: all 0.5s 0.1s, left 0.1s;
}
.menu-bottom-expand {
top: 150px;
height: 100px;
background: #FFE082;

-webkit-transition: all 0.5s, left 0.1s;
      transition: all 0.5s, left 0.1s;
}

.menu-text-expand{
 color: #000000;
 opacity: 0.8;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 1.3em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s 0.7s, font-size 0.1s;
      transition: all 0.2s 0.7s, font-size 0.1s;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I was able to change the direction of the menu opening by changing the css (.menu-global   left: 0;)  to (.menu-global   right: 0;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after you `float: right;` to `.menu`, on `.menu-global` change `left` to `left: auto` and add `right: 0;`

Comment: Thank you so much, will mark as right once the 5 minutes are up :)

Answer (score 0):

Same changes as @pavger, just adding : on .menu-global:hover, change left: 10px; to right 10px; to get the right effect :

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jZrVvg

```
.menu-global:hover {
     right: 10px;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
     transition: all 0.2s;
 }
```

@pavger sorry, i don't have enough reputation to comment your post :(